# ScrollView не открывается

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Короче есть страница с кнопками я добавляю в нее ScrollView и после этого я компилирую его, приложение открывается нормально и всё работает кроме той страницы в которую я добавил ScrollView после попытки перейти на эту страницу приложение закрывается. Ошибки нет. Что делать? код выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_factory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_frame"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="FACTORY"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_customs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_frame"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="CUSTOMS"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_factory"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-29dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_woods"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_frame"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="WOODS"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_customs"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_shoreline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_frame"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="SHORELINE"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_woods"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_interchange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_frame"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="INTERCHANGE"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_shoreline"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_the_lab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_frame"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="THE LAB"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_interchange"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_military_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_frame"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="MILITARY BASE"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_the_lab"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-14dp" />

</ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: У вас в логах должена быть точка выхода приложения, там всегда пишется. Попытайтесь запустить приложение и подключить режим отладки, после этого откройте лог и запустите ваш view, должен отобразится лог прогрузки приложения и view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основываясь на вашем коде.
Вы неправильно расположили ScrollView
Вот полностью рабочий код:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_factory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="FACTORY"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_customs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="CUSTOMS"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_factory"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-29dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_woods"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="WOODS"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_customs"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_shoreline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="SHORELINE"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_woods"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-14dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_interchange"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="INTERCHANGE"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_shoreline"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-14dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_the_lab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="THE LAB"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_interchange"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-14dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_military_base"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="MILITARY BASE"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_the_lab"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-14dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

У ScrollView должен быть только один дочерний элемент. Вам нужно "завернуть" кнопки в любую группу, например LinearLayout.